# org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException

Tags: solr, tomcat6, fedora-commons

I am using Apache Solr 4.6.0 with application called FedoraGSearch 2.6 (which claims to be compatible with Solr 4.6.0. Everytime I try using FedoraGSearch, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.lucene.index.IndexFormatTooNewException: Format version is not supported
(resource: ChecksumIndexInput(SimpleFSIndexInput(path="/var/solr/collection1/data/index/segments_1"))): 1 (needs to be between 0 and 0)
```

All this is running on a Tomcat6 installation.

When I look at the segment_1 file, it is in binary so that doesn't help me much.

I have no idea how to resolve this error. What is the cause of it, and how can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Try using Solr 4.2 rather than 4.6 per the DiscoveryGarden install guide...
https://github.com/discoverygarden/basic-solr-config/wiki/Guide-to-Setting-up-GSearch-2.6-with-Solr-4.2.0. 
Also, what version of Fedora Commons are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using Fedorea 3.6.2. I couldn't get it to work with Solr 4.2 but did get it working with Solr 3.6.2. However I have a new error that I can't track down and have created a new question for it.